# No se puede crear la instancia de clase: Java ServerFace

Tags: java, mysql, jsf

no puedo ejeecutar proyeto me dice No se puede crear la instancia de clase:
mi managed bean es el siguiente

```
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>man_articulos</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>controladores.man_articulos</managed-bean-class>

        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
</faces-config>
```

y la clase que no se puede instanciar la siguinete:
 */

```
import entidades.articulo;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import modelos.modelo_articulo;


public class man_articulos {

    private articulo actual;    
    private List lista = new ArrayList();
    private String mensaje;

    public man_articulos() {
        actual = new articulo();
        modelo_articulo modelo = new modelo_articulo();
        try {
            lista = modelo.obtener_articulos();
        } 
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            mensaje = ex.getMessage();
        }

    }

    /**
     * @return the actual
     */
    public articulo getActual() {
        return actual;
    }

    /**
     * @param actual the actual to set
     */
    public void setActual(articulo actual) {
        this.actual = actual;
    }

    /**
     * @return the lista
     */
    public List getLista() {
        return lista;
    }

    /**
     * @param lista the lista to set
     */
    public void setLista(List lista) {
        this.lista = lista;
    }

    /**
     * @return the mensaje
     */
    public String getMensaje() {
        return mensaje;
    }

    /**
     * @param mensaje the mensaje to set
     */
    public void setMensaje(String mensaje) {
        this.mensaje = mensaje;
    }
    public void buscar()
    {
        modelo_articulo modelo =new modelo_articulo();
        try{
            lista =modelo.obtener_articulos_nombre(this.actual.getArtNombre());
        }
        catch (SQLException ex)
        {
            mensaje=ex.getMessage();
        }
    }


    }
```

y mi clase de conexion:

```
public class ConexionPro {

    private Connection con = null;
    private String url;
    private String usuario;
    private String contrasena;

    public Connection conectar() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("no se puede encontrar a clase Mysql");
        }
        try
        {
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/produccion";
            usuario = "root";
            contrasena = "";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usuario, contrasena);

        } catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Errot al crear la conexion");
        }
        System.out.println("getConnection");
        return con;
    }
}
com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: No se puede crear la instancia de clase: controladores.man_articulos.
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:191)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:257)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:116)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getBase(AstValue.java:151)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:200)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:732)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:1822)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndexWithoutRowStatePreserved(UIData.java:484)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:473)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.encodeBegin(TableRenderer.java:81)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:865)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.encodeBegin(UIData.java:1133)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1854)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:458)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:134)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at modelos.modelo_articulo.obtener_articulos(modelo_articulo.java:28)
    at controladores.man_articulos.(man_articulos.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:186)
```

Comment: Hay que recordar que para usar una instancia se debe declaran los bean Históricamente, los beans de una aplicación se han declaran en su fichero de configuración WEB-INF/faces-config.xml. // nombre puede variar. debes revisar el archivo para crear una correcta instancia.

Comment: ¿Has subido el código completo de man_articulos? La referencia que tienes en el faces-config indica que está en el paquete controladores, pero en el código que has copiado no hay referencia al package.

Comment: si alli esta solo que no lo copie pero si alli esta

Comment: ¿Puedes colgar la traza de error completa?

Comment: En la traza dice lo siguiente, ahi es donde hay que fijarse : Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at modelos.modelo_articulo.obtener_articulos(modelo_articulo.java:28)
    at controladores.man_articulos.(man_articulos.java:23)